# What is the name of the interviewing/research technique where one sample generates questions for the next?

Tags: interview, qualitative-research

I'm aware of imagining there is a technique in qualitative research where responses made in one interview are explicitly used to provide prompts/new questions in subsequent interviews.

Does this have a name? It's a bit like snowball sampling, except to identify new questions rather than new samples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like [grounded theory](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grounded_theory):

> A study based on grounded theory is likely to begin with a question, or even just with the collection of qualitative data. As researchers review the data collected, ideas or concepts become apparent to the researchers. These ideas/concepts are said to "emerge" from the data.

Data are collected so as to let concepts emerge, and these emerging concepts are then used in the further collection of data. The concepts that emerge thus 'update' or 'feed back' into the next step in the empirical approach.

Comment: Many thanks... that was what I had in mind.